# Tensor product of function spaces: does $\widehat{\bigotimes}_{\pi;1\leq k\leq n}C(X_{k})^{\prime}\cong C(\prod_{k}X)^{\prime}$ hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$. Let $X_{k}$ be (non-empty) compact Hausdorff spaces for $1\leq k\leq n$. Let $X:=\prod_{k}X_{k}$ and let $\pi_{k}:X\longrightarrow$ be the projections.

It is a straightforward matter to prove that there is a unique linear map

$$\begin{array}[c]{rcl}
p &: &\bigotimes_{k}C(X_{k})^{\prime} &\longrightarrow C(X)^{\prime}
\end{array}$$

satisfying by $\langle \prod_{k}f_{k}\circ\pi_{k},  p(\otimes_{k}\varphi_{k})\rangle=\prod_{k}\langle f_{k},\varphi_{k}\rangle$ for all $(\varphi_{k})_{k}\in\prod_{k}C(X_{k})^{\prime}$ and $(f_{k})_{k}\in\prod_{k}C(X_{k})$. Moreover it holds that $\|p(\Phi)\|\leq\|\Phi\|_{\pi}$ for all $\Phi\in\bigotimes_{k}C(X_{k})^{\prime}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{\pi}$ is the *projective cross norm*. Thus $p$ extends uniquely to a continuous linear function

$$\begin{array}[c]{rcl}
p &: &\widehat{\bigotimes}_{\pi;k}C(X_{k})^{\prime} &\longrightarrow C(X)^{\prime}.
\end{array}$$

I have two questions.

**Question 1.** Is $p$ in fact an isometric map? It is easy to see that $\|p(\otimes_{k}\varphi_{k})\|=\|\otimes_{k}\varphi_{k}\|_{\pi}$, but I have not yet been able to show that this holds for all $\Phi\in\bigotimes_{k}C(X_{k})^{\prime}$.

**(Main) Question 2.** Is $p$ surjective? (By the open mapping theorem this would imply that it is open.)

**UPDATE** According to Example 4.2 and the remarks under Corollary 4.13, as well as Exercise 4.3 of *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces* (Ryan, 2002) the map $p$ is isometric. According to Theorem 4.21 ... if we replace $C(X_{k})$ by reflexive Banach spaces, $E_{k}$, then the map would be surjective if and only if $\widehat{\bigotimes}_{\pi;k}E_{k}$ is reflexive. Since $C(X_{k})$ is not reflexive, I'm not sure what can be applied here.

Comment: In the case $k=2,X_1=X_2=[0,1]$ it becomes *there is some $A=1$ such that for any $w \in L^1([0,1]^2)$ then $w(x,y) = \sum_n b_n u_n(x)v_n(y)$ where $\|v_n\|_{L^1([0,1])} =\|u_n\|_{L^1([0,1]} = 1$ and $\|b\|_{\ell^1} \le A \|w\|_{L^1([0,1]^2)}$* (If $W \in C([0,1]^2)'$ then $w=W\ast \psi_\epsilon \in L^1([0,1]^2)$ and both have almost the same $C([0,1]^2)'$ norm and $\|b\|_{\ell^1} = \|w\|_\pi \approx \|W\|_\pi \overset{?}\le A \|W\|_{C([0,1]^2)'}\approx A \|w\|_{C([0,1]^2)'} = A \|w\|_{L^1([0,1]^2)'}$). Your question is very abstract while this is down to earth

Comment: Your comment has neither a clear start nor a clear conclusion. What is the point of your computation?

Comment: It has an equivalent formulation in term of matrix norms : there exists a constant $A$ such that $\forall M, \|M\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |M_{i,j}| \ge A^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|$ for some $ \sum_n b_n u_n v_n^\top=M, \|u_n\|_1 = \|v_n\|_1=  1$